# How do i send an email using exception_notifier gem manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception-notification

I am trying the following code:

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(env, exception).deliver
```

But this message keep on appearing:

```
A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have not configured the gem in an initializer. In my controller action for notifying me of an exception I have the following

```
ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(
  request.env, 
  env["action_dispatch.exception"]
).deliver
```

I have the following in `config/initializers/exception_notifier.rb`

```
if Rails.env.production?
  MyApp::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
    email_prefix:         "[#{App.domain.pretty}] ",
    sender_address:       App.email.noreply,
    exception_recipients: App.email.exceptions,
    ignore_exceptions:    ExceptionNotifier.default_ignore_exceptions,
    normalize_subject:    true
end
```

`MyApp`, and `App.____` should all be replaced by your own values.

Comment: Where did you set `App.domain`